# Is there any tool for reading harddrive discs physically?

Tags: hard-drive

In short: I want to learn more on data forensics and now I need to pick out the discs in a harddrive (while yes I do know the dangers of this ;) ) and read them one by one. However I can't seem to find the right tools, if there are any, to do this (the reading part, not disassembling part). Thankful for any guidance in the right direction!

EDIT:
My native language is not english and I'm sorry if I'm unclear, however the intent of this question was more on the proper hardware, other than an exact copy of the harddrive, I could use to read the deassembled discs from a harddrive to get it's content to save data. What hardware is used i.e. in a forensics lab to get data from burned discs (however I wont be burning discs, just to read from discs where hardware is an issue, click of death and so on). 
Once again thankful for all the helpful answers!

Comment: Probably the closest you can get would be the modern equivalent to the old Norton Disk Doctor.  That was essentially a hex editor of disk sectors.  The program was aware of, but bypassed the filesystem organization and restrictions.  BTW the data on HDDs are not organized or ordered per disc or platter, but by cylinder.

Comment: [Hxd](http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) is a Hex Editor that will let you read and edit raw data from the hard disk.

Comment: [testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) has some advanced options that may be of use to you.

Comment: I'm really thankful for all the insightful answers here, however I'm really sorry if my buildup of the question is wrong, english is not my native language and I should really have specified this in the question I see now, but I'm looking for more of the physical tools to read the drive, line an open case harddrive where you can attach the discs and read them, other than an exacly same harddrive?

Comment: No, you were clear enough to me. Based on my prior experience working with HDDs and controllers, I doubt that operating a platter outside its original assembly is practical (or possible) except in extreme cases.  I'm guessing that the first step in recovering data is repairing the HDD so that at least the data can be read as one image.  Note that opening up the HDD requires a clean room.  I assumed that you do not have the wealth or expertise to rebuild HDDs.  Besides, if you cannot process an intact drive & filesystem, then you will have extra difficulties reconstructing a damaged disk.

Comment: Maybe you could try asking your question at [electronics.stackexchange](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions).

Comment: Thank you very much @sawdust for the help, I'm setting my goals to be able to repair the components of the drive instead of removing parts to be read somewhere else =). I'm however a very curious personality so you will most likely see me ending up in the electronics department as you recommended, thanks once again for everything =).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Linux Disk Editor

If you're OK with using a Linux based tool there is [LDE - Linux Disk Editor](http://lde.sourceforge.net/lde_use.html). Caveat is that it can only deal with Linux filesystems such as EXT2/3/4.

[image: lde #1]

[image: lde #2]

#### wxHexEditor

Another choice would be [wxHexEditor](http://www.wxhexeditor.org/). Runs on Linux, Windows, and OSX. Can handle any file system and is specifically built to deal with large files.

[image: wx #1]

#### Forensic Tool Suites

If you're interested in a full suite of tools you might want to give [BackTrack](http://www.backtrack-linux.org/) or [Kali Linux](http://www.kali.org/) a look. I would go with Kali of the two, it's the predecessor to BackTrack. It has [pretty good docs](http://docs.kali.org/) if you want to check them out first.

Comment: Thanks, this rally helped me in another field, always good the get tips on better software than I'm currently using, however my initial questions intent was on the hardware to use to read from individual discs other than an exact copy of the harddrive being used.

Answer (score 0):

As per guidance by @sawdust and @slm I need to start using the available software to start recover data and then repair the drive instead of removing and reading in other system.